# Leaflet class extend

Tags: javascript, плагин, leafletjs

Пишу плагин Leaflet, который расширяет Leaflet.Draw. При попытке написать что-то вроде:

```
L.SRTM.Draw.Feature = L.Draw.Feature.extend({ ... });
```

вылетает следующее:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Feature' of undefined

При написании:

```
L.SRTM.Draw.Feature = L.Class.extend({ ... includes: L.Draw.Feature, ... });
```

происходит то же самое.

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ в описании ошибки: класса `L.Draw` не существует. Есть `L.Control.Draw`. Впрочем, я советую забыть про Leaflet.draw (он уже почти год не обновляется, и, скорее всего, будет плохо совместим с Leaflet 1.0), а использовать [Leaflet.Editable](https://github.com/yohanboniface/Leaflet.Editable).